# PHP, (how?) is it possible to pass the $GLOBALS array into a shell_exec

Tags: php, bash

I have this basic script App1 :

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// ... do some stuff
echo $foo;
// ... do some stuff
```

I execute this script from the shell with the simple command : ./App1

For several reasons, I must passing a variable too this script **WITHOUT modify the App1 script**.

I tried to create an another script pre_App1 with this code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$GLOBALS['foo'] = "It works !"; 
echo shell_exec('./App1');
```

But when I execute the pre_App1 program :

```
./pre_App1
```

I get this error : "Undefined index: foo" 
Is there a way for passing a variable to a script without modify this script or its impossible ?

I can't modify the script, so I can't add a simply "$foo = $argv[1];" in the App1 script ;)

Thanks for some help !

Comment: So where does that script get that value from? How is `$foo` initialised? It just has an `echo $foo` without initialising `$foo` anywhere?!

Comment: Its more complicatred, and if I describe the context, this post will become really really big ;) I just want know if its possible to initialise/pass a variable to a script I can't modify

Comment: Well, in general, no. You could however write a wrapper script which creates that global variable and then just `include`s the other file.

Comment: simply & perfect, thank you :)